# Unable to correctly access my class declared inside the private area of another class

Tags: c++, queue, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I am currently working on a deep copy constructor for my queue class and I am a bit stuck with the technique of properly accessing my data encapsulated in the private area.

The queue.h file

```
class Queue
{
  public:
   Queue( const Queue& q );
   // other functions I have not yet finished yet, but will soon!

 private:
 class node  // node type for the linked list 
{
   public:
       node(int new_data, node * next_node ){
          data = new_data ;
          next = next_node ;
       }
       int data ;
       node * next ;
};

node * front_p ; 

node * back_p ;

int current_size ; 
};
```

Here is my following queue.cpp file (implementations) that contains the function

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <cstdlib>

Queue::Queue(const Queue& q ) // not sure
{

    if (front_p == NULL && back_p == NULL){
        front_p = back_p -> node(q.data, NULL); // problem here ;(
    }
        while (q != NULL)
        {
            node *ptr = new node;
            ptr->node(q.data, NULL)
            //ptr->data = q.data;
            back_p->next = ptr;
            back_p = ptr;
            q=q.next;
        }
        current_size = q.current_size;
}
```

*note that my main.cpp is not included hence there is no int main in case some thought queue.cpp was the main file. It is the implementatations of queue.h

So to explain what my code should do, I am passing the copy constructor an instance of the Queue class into the copy constructor and I want to access the data in q. I have tried using q.data, but that does not work out so well and I realize that the "data" I am trying to access **is in another class.**

Of course I thought maybe I should try doing something like this q.node.data but that is just wishful thinking.

My following error is copied here from terminal:

```
queue.cpp:14:23: error: invalid use of ‘Queue::node::node’
   front_p = back_p -> node(q.data, NULL);
                   ^
queue.cpp:14:30: error: ‘const class Queue’ has no member named ‘data’
   front_p = back_p -> node(q.data, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole block of code you're having problems with is meaningless.

```
if (front_p == NULL && back_p == NULL){
    // stuff
}
```

This is a constructor.  `front_p` and `back_p` don't have pre-existing values.  So the `if` is useless.  The `this` object is *always* empty at this point.

```
front_p = back_p -> node(q.data, NULL); // problem here ;(
```

That line is meaningless from a code perspective.  `back_p` isn't set, so using the `->` operator on it is horribly wrong.  It's not clear what you were even trying to do here.  Did you mean

```
front_p = back_p = new node(q.front_p->data, NULL);
```

But what if `q.front_p` is NULL (the other queue was empty)?

Your problems continue

```
while (q != NULL)
```

`q` is not a pointer that can be NULL.  Presumably you want to walk the list of items contained in `q`, starting from `q->front_p`.

Comment: Thanks! This really cleared a lot of problems for me and some that I did not think of. I've realized that I have a lot of redundant things in my code haha....